# Why I cant run my chat application GUI using a button of another class and Why my GUI freezing after calling my host program?

Tags: java, swing, sockets, user-interface, chat

**This is my GUI form and using this form i can call my Host(Server) chat application and Client Chat application using Host button amd Client button.**

```
package Chat;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class gu extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    
    public gu() {
        initComponents();
    }

    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("Client");
        jButton1.setToolTipText("");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("Host");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(134, 134, 134)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 134, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(65, 65, 65)
                .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 119, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(156, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(165, 165, 165)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 60, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 60, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(198, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        
        
            Client1 client = new Client1();
            client.Client();
            
        
    }                                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
       
        
       
            Server1 server = new Server1();
        try {
            server.Server();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(gu.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        
        
    }                                        

    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(gu.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(gu.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(gu.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(gu.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
       
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new gu().setVisible(true);
                
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

**This is my Server Chat application code.**

```
package Chat;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;


public class Server1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    static ServerSocket ss;
    static Socket s;
    static DataInputStream dis;
    static DataOutputStream dout;

    
    public Server1() {
        initComponents();
    }

   
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea2 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea1.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

        jButton1.setText("Send");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextArea2.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea2.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTextArea2);

        jLabel1.setText("Server");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(20, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 127, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 635, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 506, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                            .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 117, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                .addGap(21, 21, 21))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(12, 12, 12)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 36, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 242, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 84, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(49, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }                    

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        
        try {
            String msg = "";
            msg = jTextArea2.getText();
            dout.writeUTF(msg);
            jTextArea2.setText("");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            //handle the exception
        }


    }                                        

    
    public void Server() throws IOException {
       
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Server1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Server1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Server1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Server1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        

      
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Server1().setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        try {
            String msgin = "";
            
             
            
            ss = new ServerSocket(9999);
           
            s = ss.accept();
            jTextArea1.setText(jTextArea1.getText() + "Connected to a Client");
           
           
            dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            
            
             

            while (!msgin.equals("q")) {

                msgin = dis.readUTF();
                jTextArea1.setText(jTextArea1.getText() + "\n\n Server :- " + msgin);

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }

    }

                 
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private static javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea2;
      
}
```

**This is my client chat application**

```
package Chat;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;


public class Client1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    static Socket s;
    static DataInputStream dis;
    static DataOutputStream dout;

    
    public Client1() {
        initComponents();
    }

   
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
               
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea2 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea1.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

        jButton1.setText("Send");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextArea2.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea2.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTextArea2);

        jLabel1.setText("Client");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(20, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 127, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 635, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 506, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                            .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 117, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                .addGap(21, 21, 21))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(12, 12, 12)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 36, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 242, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 84, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(49, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }               

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        try {
            String msg = "";
            msg = jTextArea2.getText();
            dout.writeUTF(msg);
            jTextArea2.setText("");

        } catch (Exception e) {
           
        }


    }                                        

    
    public void Client() {
       
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Client1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Client1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Client1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Client1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Client1().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        
        
        
        try {
            String msgin = "";

            s = new Socket("localhost", 9999); //ip address of 
            
            
            dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            
            

            while (!msgin.equals("exit")) {

                msgin = dis.readUTF();
                jTextArea1.setText(jTextArea1.getText() + "\n\n Server :- " + msgin);

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }

    }

                  
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private static javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea2;
            
}
```

[This my main GUI and using the client button I can run client class GUI but if I click the host button all the GUIs are freezing and Host GUI did not run[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssx6S.png)

[this is my frozen GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LmKL.jpg)

Please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

you need use Thread to Split​ the process on class gu.java when click button host

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Server1 server = new Server1();
            try {
                server.Server();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(gu.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It is now working. Again Mr. Ra Ven thank you for your help and kindness.

Answer (score 0):

and add thread to call client to

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Client1 client = new Client1();
            client.Client();
        }
    }).start();
```